# Optimization on non-convex set

Tags: calculus-of-variations, linear-programming, global-optimization

Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $f\in L^2(\Omega)$ be a given function. Consider the optimization problem
$$\mathrm{min} \int_\Omega u(x) f(x) \,dx\,,$$
where a minimum is considered over all functions $u\in X(\Omega): = \{ v \in L^2(\Omega) : v(x)\in\{0,1\} \ \forall x\in \Omega\}$. The set $X(\Omega)$ is obviously non-convex. Is it true that this non-convex optimization problem has a unique minimum which is $u(x)=0$ if $f(x)\geq 0$ and $u(x)=1$ if $f(x)<0$?

Comment: I would say, assume that there is another minimizer and show that you improve it by modifying it towards the one you stated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer below. I just think if some additional assumption about $f$ could be helpful, e.g., $f\in BV(\Omega)$ and $|f = 0|=\emptyset$.

Comment: @mlogm : I don't understand your comment. Are you satisfied with the answer? If not, why not?

Comment: I think one should also take into account the fact that if $u_\ast$ is a mnimizer then $u_{\ast\ast}=u_\ast$ a.e. on the set $|f\neq 0|$ and $u_{\ast\ast}\neq u_\ast$ on the set $|f=0|$ is also a minimizer.

Comment: Your latter comment is incomprehensible to me as well: (i) What is $u_{**}$ is your comment? (ii) What do you mean by "take into account" in this case? -- Concerning (i), if you mean $u_{**}$ is as in my answer, it is stated there: "If $u_{**}\in X(\Omega)$ and $u_{**}=u_*$ almost everywhere (a.e.) on the set $[f\ne0]:=\{x\colon f(x)\ne0\}$, then $\int u_{**}f=\int u_*f$, so that $u_{**}$ is also a minimizer."

Comment: Previous comment continued: This simple fact is, not only stated, but also properly taken into account, by concluding that "$u_{**}\in X(\Omega)$ is a minimizer if and only if $u_{**}=u_*$ a.e. on the set $[f\ne0]$." What else do you want here?

Comment: I mean that on the set $|f=0|$, $u_{\ast\ast}$ and $u_\ast$ may have different values and still be minimizers, therefore there is no uniqueness.

Comment: Indeed, there is no uniqueness. This is a fact, which is already stated in my answer (where the set of minimizers is fully characterized), and one cannot possibly alter or get rid of facts. So, again, what else do you want here?

Answer (score 2):

Yes (mainly). That $u_*:=1_{f<0}$ is a minimizer (of $\int uf$ over all $u\in X(\Omega)$) follows because, if $0\le u\le1$, then
$$uf-u_*f=(u-u_*)f\ge0, \tag{1}\label{1}$$
whence
$$\int u_*f\le\int uf.$$

The minimizer is not unique, though. If $u_{**}\in X(\Omega)$ and $u_{**}=u_*$ almost everywhere (a.e.) on the set $[f\ne0]:=\{x\colon f(x)\ne0\}$, then $\int u_{**}f=\int u_*f$, so that $u_{**}$ is also a minimizer. Vice versa, if $u_{**}\in X(\Omega)$ is a minimizer, then, by \eqref{1},
$$\int|u_{**}-u_*|\,|f|=\int(u_{**}-u_*)\,f=\int u_{**}\,f-\int u_*\,f=0,$$
so that $u_{**}=u_*$ a.e. on the set $[f\ne0]$.
Thus, $u_{**}\in X(\Omega)$ is a minimizer if and only if $u_{**}=u_*$ a.e. on the set $[f\ne0]$.

---

The same conclusion holds with $\{v\in L^2(\Omega)\colon v(x)\in[0,1] \ \forall x\in\Omega\}$ in place of $X(\Omega)=\{v\in L^2(\Omega)\colon v(x)\in\{0,1\} \ \forall x\in\Omega\}$.